Insert geography[] in postgres (postgis)
I want to insert a row which has a value of type geography[] in a column defined with the same type. (an array of coordinates)
I can manage to insert rows when the value of a column is ::geography (a single pair of coordinates) with the following query:
insert into foo (position) values (ST_Point(30, 45)::geography);

Now I have tried
insert into bar (position_array) values ( '{ ST_Point(30, 45)::geography }' ) ;

And I have also tried
insert into bar (position_array) values ( '{ ST_Point(30, 45)}'::geography[] ) ;

But I get:
"ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry

I can also insert empty arrays and I have checked I have to use the apices like the array literal is a string but I am sure this is trivial for somebody with some postgres background

I don't have PostGIS to test but how about insert into foo (position) values (ARRAY[ST_Point(30, 45)::geography]);

@AdrianKlaver that was it, thanks
